# Outlook & Google Calendar two-way sync (bidirectional, not read only)

Tags: windows, gratis, calendar, google-apps

Our company recently changed to Outlook 2013. I need a way to:

- Synchronize my Google Calendar to Outlook 2013
- Edit the Outlook calendar in Google Calendar and have it sync later to Outlook

I realize Google has a Calendar Sync for Outlook, but it is only for Google Apps user. We are not one of those users. We also have Outlook for Web Access (OWA), if that simplifies configuration with offered solutions.

Ideally, the software solution would be free, but also open to paying for a license that is one-time unlimited use. The solution I am looking for is a software that I can install on a Windows 7 PC.